# Get value from html label assiociated with radiobutton using FOR attribute

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, for-attribute

A html form with radio buttons which is assiociated with HTML label which looks like this.

```
<form action="demo_form.aspx">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

how to get values when user clicks radio buttons either using java script or using server-side script (ASP.Net- C#) ? And also which one of this will be more appropriate to use.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: i am trying to use javascript, but jquery will also do.

Comment: `values` means? radio value or form elements value

Comment: its radio value. If user selects any options and submits it i should able to get that selected radio value.

Comment: It can be done with pure javascript. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Script:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btn-submit');
    btnSubmit.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#myform input[type="radio"][name="sex"]');                 
        for (var i = 0; i < radioInputs.length; i++) {
            if (radioInputs[i].checked)
            {
                var value = getlabelforValue(radioInputs[i]);
                alert(value);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    };
};

function getlabelforValue(inputname) {
    var labelElements = document.querySelectorAll('#myform label');
    for (var i = 0; labelElements[i]; i++) {
        console.log(labelElements[i]);
        if (labelElements[i].getAttribute('for') == inputname.getAttribute('id')) {
            return labelElements[i].innerText || labelElements[i].textContent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Html:

```
<form id="myform" action="demo_form.aspx">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male" /><br />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Here is the** <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtzc4/4/)**</kbd>

Or

In code behind you can do this to get value.

`string radioValue = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form['sex']);`

Comment: i needed label value actually. you used radio name to get the value is it possible to get label value.

Comment: label.innerHTML is working but label.innerText is not working wonder why ?

Comment: @SDKLive `innerText` is non-standard, it significantly differs from `textContent`, because first one is doing pretty printing (for example, <br/> are converted to new lines), while second one - is not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
1. add to each input tag attribute class="sex".
2. use jquery you can do like this:

```
$('.sex').click(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Reworked on script given by @bios. This is shorter version of the script.

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btn-submit');
        btnSubmit.onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#myform input[type="radio"][name="sex"]');                 
            var labelElements = document.querySelectorAll('#myform label');

            for (var i=0; i<radioInputs.length; i++){

                for (var j = 0; labelElements[j]; j++) {

                    if (radioInputs[i].checked)
                    {
                        var rdval = radioInputs[i].getAttribute('id');
                        var lblval = labelElements[j].getAttribute('for');

                        if(rdval == lblval){                    
                            var val = labelElements[j].textContent;
                            alert(val);                 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
   };
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="demo_form.aspx">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male" /><br />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```